# Why does google-api-dotnet-client BuildRelease.exe clone the entire contrib repository

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

BuildRelease will clone the entire contrib repository.  What is the purpose of doing this?  It slows down the build process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that is based on the fact that we store all the version history in [contrib](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/?repo=contrib) repository.
When we create a new build of Google.Apis, we add a new folder with the content of the release (e.g[. 1.3.0-beta](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/?repo=contrib#hg/1.3.0-beta/Generated/Bin)).

We use BuildRelease.exe mainly to create a new release of the library, so out of curiosity - why do you use it?

Comment: Does cloning that entire repository make sense in the context of a local only build?  I am using it to make sure some customizations I have made for building strongly named assemblies and a "unified" assembly do not break anything in the build process.

Comment: No it doesn't make sense. Feel free to open a new issue in our issue tracker - https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/list